# how i can fetch image in JSON and make slide screen with these images?

Tags: java, android, json

I am beginner with Android programming and I am working with a small project.

I need to fetch data from server using *JSON* ( I do this step).

I do not know how to make slide screen with these images and I do not know how to start.

Can any one give me an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Volley For fetching the data learn some from this link
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/
For showing images use Picasso
http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/gridview-tutorial-using-the-picasso-library.html
Then use Image Slider refer below
http://javapapers.com/android/android-image-slider-tutorial/

Please Use google to search before asking here.